# What is the use to send spitting/chunk files to server

Tags: android

I have to upload big video files to a server, but it's taking too long to upload, so I decided to split/chunk the files and then send them to the server

After splitting my files, I get a response like the following:

```
[ /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.001, /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.002, /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.003, /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.004, /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.005, /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.006, /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.007, /storage/emulated/0/1493357699.mp4.008 ]
```

**My thought is what is the use to upload spitting/chunk file to server?**

### My code for splitting files:

```
 public static List<File> splitFile(File f) {

        try {

            int partCounter = 1;
            List<File> result = new ArrayList<>();
            int sizeOfFiles = 1024 * 1024;// 1MB
            byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfFiles];
            // create a buffer of bytes sized as the one chunk size

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            String name = f.getName();

            int tmp = 0;
            while ((tmp = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                File newFile = new File(f.getParent(), name + "." + String.format("%03d", partCounter++));
                // naming files as <inputFileName>.001, <inputFileName>.002, ...
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                out.write(buffer, 0, tmp);//tmp is chunk size. Need it for the last chunk,
                // which could be less then 1 mb.
                result.add(newFile);
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You mean, what should you use to upload those chunks ?

Comment: no no my doubt is what is use of uploading spitting/chunks instead of uploading large file,Because some one saying send chunks of big video files

Comment: @RujulGandhi Please read the actual question and links that you find. That is completely unrelated

Comment: I made something about sending chunk files to server using Socket.io and Nodejs. I have an issue about it your code does not write last chunk in specify directory. So when i want to get last chunk my app crashed

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented in one of my projects. I see two primary reasons:

1. To achieve multi-threaded / multiple connection for uploading chunks. You can upload multiple chunks at the same time.
2. Stop/Resume uploading of rest of the chunks if either of the chunk fails to upload (depending on server response)

Comment: sending chunk files means uploading fastly? instead sending big file